# buttons (text or images)

Tags: html, web-development, css, website-design

I would like to know if I should create CSS buttons or image buttons for my site. What is better? Problem is that the text is formatted with Helvetica Neue ( I like that font very much) and I can't use it as a web font because of copyright issues.

If I create the buttons in CSS they look beautiful in the browser but get resized when the user has chosen a different text-size for their browsers.

Image buttons have the advantage I can embed my font but do not look that good as CSS buttons. Also in that case I had to make Retina-versions for the buttons (just for the future when any PC has a Retina-display).

Can someone please help me in this tricky situation? Does anyone know a web-safe alternative to Helvetica Neue? Should I disable the resizing of my button div-containers? What's today's standard when it comes to website buttons?

TIA!

Comment: if a user has chosen to see smaller fonts, its because they want to see smaller fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, Linotype does offer a *Neue Helvetica* font that's licensed for web use.

## Web-safe Alternatives

But if you don't want to pay for the web license, the obvious web-safe alternatives to *Helvetica Neue* are *Helvetica* and *Arial*. If you simply use `sans-serif`, it'll default to the user's platform's default sans serif font, which is typically:

- *Helvetica* for **Mac**
- *Arial* for **Windows**
- *Droid* or *Roboto* for **Android**
- *Deja Vu*, *Bitstream Vera Sans*, or *Arial* (if MS fonts have been installed) for ***nix**

For *nix users, you'll probably want to specify `Arial` or `Bitstream Vera Sans` to get a more perceptually similar *Helvetica* analog than the default sans serif font many *nix OSes use (e.g. *Deja Vu*).

## FOSS Fonts

Alternatively, you can embed these free open source fonts:

### *Liberation Sans*

- Open source alternative to *Helvetica* and *Arial*
- Part of the greater [*Liberation Fonts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) family of GPL-2-licensed fonts sponsored by Red Hat
- Available in both [`.sfd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FontForge) source files and ready-to-use `.ttf` binaries in the Liberation™ Fonts collection [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) from the Fedora Project

### *Arimo*

- [SIL Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/OFL) (OFL) webfont-ready typeface
- Design by Ascender Fonts to look like *Arial*
- Available as a webfont on [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Arimo), Typekit, etc. and as a TrueType Font on [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/arimo)

### *FreeSans*

- GNU licensed and webfont-ready *Helvetica* / *Arial* replacement
- part off the [*Free UCS Outline Fonts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_UCS_Outline_Fonts) donated by URW++ Design & Development
- Available in `.woff`, `.otf`, and `.ttf` binaries, as well as `.sfd` source [by direct FTP](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/) or from the [GNU Free Fonts](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) and [Free UCS Outline Fonts](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) sites

I generally prefer to use CSS/text buttons whenever possible, as it's more semantically correct, requires less bandwidth, and is less work. However, if you make an image button and use proper accessibility techniques (alt text or a screen-reader-accessible text label), then it should be alright as well. It just depends on how much work you're willing to do for the perceived extra aesthetic benefit.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for that great post! This helps a lot and you saved my day!:)